# Handling double tap event in metro Application

Tags: winrt-xaml

using `gridTest.doubleTapped += DoubleTapEvent` actually very rarely detects the double tap.
Is there any work arunds or some thing to get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i provided a work around in my app by adding a dispatcher tier and that too keeping an interval of approx 300 milli seconds.

Heres dispatcher timer code

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(300);
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();

public void timer_Tick(object sender, object args){ // handle the code here and dont forget to stop the timer}
```

I know this is a bad practice but it helps. and can be used as a work around if in hurry :)